# Using an INNER JOIN without returning any columns from the joined table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Running an `INNER JOIN` type of query, i get duplicate column names, which can pose a problem. This has been covered here extensively and i was able to find the solution to this problem, asides from it being fairly logical, by `SELECT`ing only the columns i need.

However, i would like to know how i could run such a query without actually returning any of the columns from the joined table.

**This is my MySQL query**

```
SELECT * FROM product z 
    INNER JOIN crosslink__productXmanufacturer a
    ON z.id = a.productId
WHERE 
    (z.title LIKE "%search_term%" OR z.search_keywords LIKE "%search_term%")
AND
    z.availability = 1 
AND 
    a.manufacturerId IN (22,23,24)
```

**Question**

How would i modify this MySQL query in order to return only columns from `product` and **none** of the columns from `crosslink__productXmanufacturer`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the table name to the `*`. Replace

```
SELECT * FROM product z
```

with

```
SELECT z.* FROM product z
```

Comment: The simplicity of this brings me to shame! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Often when you are doing this, the intention may be clearer using `in` or `exists` rather than a `join`.  The `join` is being used for filtering, so putting the condition in the `where` clause makes sense:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE (p.title LIKE '%search_term%' OR p.search_keywords LIKE '%search_term%') AND
      p.availability = 1 AND 
      exists (SELECT 1
              FROM pXm
              WHERE pXm.productId = p.id AND pxm.manufacturerId IN (22, 23, 24)
             );
```

With the proper indexes, this should run at least as fast as the `join` version (the index is `crosslink__productXmanufacturer(productId, manufacturerId)`.  In addition, you don't have to worry about returning duplicate records, if there are multiple matches in `crosslink__productXmanufacturer`.

You may notice two other small changes I made to the query.  First, the table aliases are abbreviates for the table names, making the logic easier to follow.  Second, the string constants use single quotes (the ANSI standard) rather than double quotes.  Using single quotes *only* for string and date constants helps prevent inadvertent syntax errors.

Comment: This is valuable input and helped me understand the issue more entirely. Thank you!